# Maths olympiad problem

Tags: polynomials

What is the only integer $a$ for which there does not exist any third degree polynomial $p(x)$ that $$p(2)=11, p(11)=2, p(31)=a, p(52)=2011$$

Comment: Take $p(x) = k_0 + k_1x + k_2x^2 + k_3x^3$, construct the system of equations and conclude result.

Comment: The answer is 562.

Comment: And that is the uniquesolution...

Comment: @Fabian Exactly.

Comment: @uniquesolution thank you for the comment , cuold you give me your solution please?

Comment: @AlvinLepik I ve tried to do it but It is inconclusive

Comment: @Neo Where exactly did you run into difficulty?

Comment: I solved the system but couldn't manage to exclude 562

Comment: @Neo your objective is to not solve the system. That's not what the problem demands. E: Ennar beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$. Then we have linear system

\begin{align}
2^3A+2^2B+2C+D&=11\\
11^3A+11^2B+11C+D&=2\\
31^3A+31^2B+31C+D&=a\\
52^3A+52^2B+52C+D&=2011\\
\end{align}

Now, we don't really want to solve this. It is enough to know that there will always be a unique solution for any $a$ (see [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)). Instead, let us think what solution, with respect to $a$, will not yield a cubic polynomial: it's the one where $A = 0$. Thus, we simplify the system to

\begin{align}
2^2B+2C+D&=11\\
11^2B+11C+D&=2\\
52^2B+52C+D&=2011\\
\end{align}
 and after we solve it, we can calculate $a = 31^2B+31C+D$. Can you finish it now?

Comment: The question is whether *you* could finish it now, Ennar.

Comment: @uniquesolution, of course I can. But I won't. I stopped solving linear systems by hand after passing my linear algebra exam (excluding while teaching it).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: That would have to be when the four points lie on a quadratic. (Explain why)

Comment: Because a 3 grade polynom can't have a quadratic growth

Comment: @Neo Better said: because there always exists a polynomial of degree at most 3 going through those points. Now consider when a polynomial of degree ***at most*** 3 is *not* a $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial.